# Piano tuning- tuning pin is far too small for tuning lever

Tags: piano, tuning

I wanted to learn to tune a piano by myself, and bought a relatively cheap size #2 star tuning lever (~$40) for the job. The tuning pins are far too small for my lever.

I am looking for either a place I could find tuning levers of appropriate size or a substitute that will not damage my piano (I have been looking at harp tuning tools as an option).

More details:

The tuning pin is so small that it does not catch on the tuning lever (I am able to rotate the tuning lever freely almost without resistance).

With some quick estimation done by a bit of scotch tape and pencil, I estimate that the tuning pins are likely a full millimeter below size 2. I do not think the lever is at fault, as I have some spare #2 pins that fit perfectly with the lever.

If it is of any help, the piano is made by Young Chang (a Korean manufacturer) and has the letters "CM110" on its frame.

Edit: The pins don't appear to be worn down in particular. The piano has been succesfully tuned by professionals before.

Answer (score 4):

If you have pins too small for a #2, chances are you've got a really, really old piano. Do you have the name and serial number? Is it an upright, a grand, or a square grand? I'm thinking square  grand. They are very old and have tiny pins. Square grands are inferior in many ways and very difficult to work on. Contact a piano supply house like Schaff.

Registered Piano Technician.

Addendum. I just read it's a Young Chang. You may have bought a hammer that is not a #2.

You have spare tips but YC are #2. Are you sure the tips are #2?

Perhaps the pressure bar is in the way and you can't get the tip low enough. Have you tried other pins?

You can read more at [How to Tune Pianos](https://howtotunepianos.com).

Answer (score 2):

I have been tuning pianos (part-time) for a few years, and I have never encountered a piano where the standard tuning tools would not fit.

That said, a little bit of research suggests that there are [different sizes available](http://www.howardpianoindustries.com/one-piece-tuning-hammer-head-and-tip/)* for the tuning head. On better tuning hammers, the tuning tip and the lever are two separate pieces. You can purchase one of those hammers, then a tuning tip suitable for your pin size, and swap the tip as necessary.

<sub>*I am not affiliated with this company, but I have purchased their products in the past and they are great.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Tuning pins do indeed come in different sizes, and although a #2 tip fits most sizes I have come across a few pianos where the tuning pins are so small that tuning with the #2 tip is impossible. It sounds like you need to purchase a size #1 tip and a tuning tip wrench. Here's what the wrench looks like: http://www.howardpianoindustries.com/piano-tuning-lever-tip-wrench/  (I'm assuming by the $40 price tag on your tuning lever that it allows for interchangeable tips.)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, piano tuning pins and tools come in various sizes.  The fact that you bought a #2 is a strong indication that there are other sizes!

Information [HERE](http://www.pianoparts.com/tips/)